# Pandas: Filter datefield for each unique cell values in a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` as follows

```
YearMonth    CustID    Values
201901       12231     400
201902       12231     233
201903       12231     244
201904       12231     355
201901       12235     114
201902       12235     133
201903       12235     144
201904       12235     205
```

In the above, I have `CustID` and its corresponding values (`Values`) for each month (`YearMonth`).

Objective:

I would like to get a dataframe where for each client data will be till `201903` i.e. March 2019 from `201901` i.e. January 2019. So the resultant `df` looks like

```
YearMonth    CustID    Values
201901       12231     400
201902       12231     233
201903       12231     244
201901       12235     114
201902       12235     133
201903       12235     144
```

I have converted `YearMonth` to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime()`.

How to get the above dataframe? Should I filter first and then `groupby(['CustID'])`? Or any other way out?

Comment: `df[df['YearMonth'].le('2019-03')& df['YearMonth'].ge('2019-01')]`?

Comment: @Quang Hoang: This has worked and more generic towards any year and month. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

what about simply:

```
df = df[(df.YearMonth.ge(201901))&(df.YearMonth.le(201903))]
```

Comment: TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and int

Comment: do not convert YearMonth to datetime or use '201901' instead of 201901